# Android app to download Zipped JSon, best approach?

Tags: android, json, zip

I have an Android app that is currently in the Google Play store. On my server, I generate Zip files containing JSON information. The server takes parameters from the Android app and generates an appropriate Zip file which the Android app downloads, unzips and processes.

I currently user he AndroidHttpClient method, but I suspect the HTTPUrlConnection would have been a better choice.

What would the approach be for using HTTPUrlConnection?

Will it handle situations where the Android app may make a call on a public Wifi which could cause a redirect? Is there any sample code that I could reference for doing this?

Thanks

JOhn

Answer (score 0):

terramia.net/painter/HTTPClient/doc/urlcon_vs_httpclient.html to the pros and cons of httpclient and httpurlconection.

yes HTTPUrlConnection  can be a better chocice.

why are you ziping at server and than downloading and than processing, please write some apis that sorer can respond on yours request and can send json data straight. it will save time complexity and space-complexity to some extent. just treat as my suggestion.